# How can I write this sentence correctly?

Tags: verbs, will-be-going

How can I write the following sentence correctly:

If you will do all that you will write here, all your dreams will come true

Comment: It depends on how badly you do want your dreams to come true, that's all.

Comment: There is no way to write that sentence correctly. Even if the grammar were correct, the meaning isn't.

Answer (score 2):

as an idiom:

> If you did all that you wrote, your dreams would have come true.

or literally:

> If you do everything you have written, your dreams will come true.

**note:** Your sentence currently implies:

```
cause: you would do everything you have written
effect: your dreams come true
```

this means that if you *will* do it, your dreams would come true. Therefore, your dreams would come true before you did everything you wrote. I assumed you meant that if you do it, then your dreams come true.

Answer (score 1):

If connotes the subjunctive. The subjunctive takes the second person past tense of the verb *to be.*

Try:

*If you were to do what you write, all of your dreams will come true.*

Try:

*If you were to do what you write, your dreams must come true.*

Try:

*If you were to do what you write, your dreams could come true.*

Try:

*When you do what you have written, your dreams likely will come true.*

The subjunctive is a *verb mood* that represents an act or state (not as a fact but) as contingent or possible, such as a wish, a desire, or an imaginary situation. Subjunctive statements are contrary to fact.

Comment: "Contract to fact" ??

Comment: What do you mean by _contract to the fact_?

Comment: I mean that I don't understand it, because it is not a normal expression. Do you mean '*contrary* to fact'?

Comment: It was a typo. It's not a question of me meaning anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [conditional sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence#Grammar_of_conditional_sentences).

Considering that I don't know the context of your sentence, I'll adjust it to the four types one by one. All of them are grammatically correct, but only one will fit the context or the meaning it's supposed to have.

Zero conditional:

> If you do all that you write here, all your dreams come true.

Conditional I:

> If you do all that you write here, all your dreams will come true.

Conditional II:

> If you did all that you write here, all your dreams would come true.

Conditional III:

> If you had done all that you write here, all your dreams would have come true.

Mixed conditional:

> If you did all that you write here, all your dreams would have come true.